# Unable to maintain size of grid view inside recycler view?

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

After trying a lot I am here to post my problem here and hope that I will get a solution.
I am trying to populate A gridView inside recyclerview but at every position I have different item in grid view , The problem I am facing that Suppose I have 2
items at position 0, and 6 item at position 1 my recycler view took space of six item each time , It does not populate by displaying only two item at 0 position,
How do I achieve this :

My RecyclerView Adapter code is :-

```
public class RecyclerViewDashItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDashItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    WacsDashboardItemResponse wacsDashboardItemResponse;
    GridViewItemBaseAdapter gridViewItemBaseAdapter;

    public RecyclerViewDashItemAdapter(Context mContext, WacsDashboardItemResponse wacsDashboardItemResponse) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.wacsDashboardItemResponse = wacsDashboardItemResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_dash_item_adapter, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        gridViewItemBaseAdapter = new GridViewItemBaseAdapter(mContext,
                wacsDashboardItemResponse.subGroup.get(position).itemArray);

        holder.gridViewDashItem.setAdapter(gridViewItemBaseAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return wacsDashboardItemResponse.subGroup.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        GridView gridViewDashItem;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            gridViewDashItem = (GridView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewDashItem);
        }
    }
}
```

My xml for recyclerView adapter  is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewDashItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:columnWidth="300dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My GridView Code is :-

```
public class GridViewItemBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    List<WacsDashboardItemResponse.SubGroup.ItemArray> itemArray;

    public GridViewItemBaseAdapter(Context mContext, List<WacsDashboardItemResponse.SubGroup.ItemArray> itemArray) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.itemArray = itemArray;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return itemArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(mContext);
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_dash_item, null);
            TextView itemName = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            itemName.setText(itemArray.get(position).itmeDesc);


        }
        return gridView;
    }
}
```

My Xml for grid view is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.orbitsysindia.repairordermanagement.servicereception.util.custom.TextViewMedium
        android:id="@+id/itemName"
        style="@style/textColorBlack_14sp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check Engine" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wiperblade" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have different different item at each position , How can I solve problem of height of each section.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix the height of gridview item as currently it is matchparent so it's taking maximum height

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="320dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<com.orbitsysindia.repairordermanagement.servicereception.util.custom.TextViewMedium
    android:id="@+id/itemName"
    style="@style/textColorBlack_14sp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check Engine" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/wiperblade" />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme" />
```

Comment: I said my all item are showing correctly , I have to different items count  at different position suppose at position 0 two position 1 six , But my recycler view take height of six item section so in 0 section It show two item and space blank for another four item then it goes to the first position

Comment: can you please attach a screen shoot for better understanding

Comment: Hey @yash786 please check the attachment above

Comment: @Champandorid provide me your mail id for assisting you a better solution

Comment: eduandabhi@gmail.com kindly provide if you can